# Program runs byt cant get the correct numbers

Tags: c++, algorithm

### Heading

- - The below is code for Horner's Algorithm. When I run it, after I
    input the variables,witch is n=3,z=1,a=[-3,2,3,-1],c=[-1,2,3].Now i
    get correct numbers until t[1][2] after that the algorithm fails can
    you find the problem? The correct answers is : 
    t[1][3]=-9
    t[2][1]=6 
    t[2][2]=9 
    t[3][1]=4 
    dp[0]=-9 
    dp[1]=9 
    dp[2]=8 
    dp[3]=-6

  ### Heading 2

  enter code here

> ```
>     #include <iostream>
>     #include "math.h"
>     #include <cstdlib>
>
>     using namespace std;
>
>     int fact(int i)
>     {
>         int k=1,j;
>         for(j=1;j<=i;j++)
>         {
>             k=k*j;
>         }
>         return(k);
>     }
>
>     int main()
>     {
>         int n,i,j;
>         cout<<"give n"<<endl;
>         cin>>n;
>
>         int a[n+1],z,c[n],t[n+1][n],dp[n];
>         cout<<"give z"<<endl;
>         cin>>z;
>
>         for (i=0;i<n+1;i++)
>         {
>             cout <<"give a"<<endl;
>             cin >>a[i];
>         }
>         for (j=1;j<n+1;j++)
>         {
>             cout <<"give c"<<endl;
>             cin >>c[j];
>         }
>         for (j=0;j<=n;j++)
>         {
>             t[0][j]=a[n-j];
>         }
>         for (i=0;i<=n+1;i++)
>         {
>             t[i][0]=a[n];
>         }
>         for (i=1;i<=n;i++)
>         {
>             for (j=1;j<=n-i+1;j++)
>             {
>                 t[i][j]=t[i][j-1]*(z-c[n+2-i-j])+t[i-1][j];
>                 cout<<t[i][j]<<endl;
>             }
>         }
>
>         for (i=0;i<=n;i++)
>         {
>             if(i==0)
>             {
>                 dp[i]=t[i+1][n-i];
>             }
>             else
>             {
>                 dp[i]=(fact(i))*(t[i+1][n-i]);
>                 cout<<dp[i]<<endl;
>             }
>         }
>         return(0);
>     }
> ```

enter code here

Comment: if(i=0) looks incorrect for sure.  I think you want if(i==0)

Comment: Can you re-write your code with variable names that actually mean something? Right now I'm lost.

Comment: What... oh... dat formatting! My eyes are bleeding!

Comment: easy guyz this is my first question better like this?

Comment: Pro Tip: If you keep on [deleting your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20316953/when-i-run-my-program-it-runs-infinite-at-the-same-number) and re-asking them, you will be [banned from asking any more questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th).

Comment: Frankly, this looks like an entry to the IOCCC (International Obfuscated C Code Contest) to me. It infinitely increases readability when you use meaningful labels for your variables.

Comment: guyz can you help here too plz ? thx :D

Answer (score 0):

You assign 0 to i instead of comparing i to 0 in this code

```
for (i=0;i<=n;i++)
    {
        if(i=0) // Wrong, change to if (i == 0) or if(!i) since i == 0 == !true
        {
            dp[i]=t[i+1][n-i];
        }
        else
        {
            dp[i]=(fact(i))*(t[i+1][n-i]);
            cout<<dp[i]<<endl;
        }

    }    return(0);
```